# при потключении к h2 в jar вылетает nullpointerexception

Tags: java, jar, h2

Создаю десктоп приложение на джаве. Для хранение данных решил использовать H2 бд. Подключаюсь к ней при помощи такого url:

```
"jdbc:h2:~/aleksei"
```

где aleksei - название моей бд.
Если запускать экспортированный jar на своем компьютере всё нормально работает, но если сделать это с другого компьютера (предварительно поменяв url к aleksei.h2.db который засунул в корень проекта на "jdbc:h2:file:/aleksei") вылетает nullpointerexception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at gui.GUI.initialize(GUI.java:89)
at gui.GUI.<init>(GUI.java:71)
at gui.GUI$1.run(GUI.java:58)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

GUI.java:89 - просто создаю лейбл с текстом, который беру из бд.

```
JLabel topicName = new JLabel(topicService.getById(1L).getName());
```

так создаю датасорс

```
  private DataSource initiateDataSource() {
    BasicDataSource  bds = new BasicDataSource();
    //bds.setUrl("jdbc:h2:~/aleksei"); этот вариант работает, но только на моем pc (на других - npe)
    bds.setUrl("jdbc:h2:file:/aleksei");//пробую этот вариант, чтоб работала на других компьютерах, но в таком случае даже у меня вылетает npe.
    bds.setUsername("aleksei");
    bds.setPassword("");
    return bds;
}
```

В оф. документации написано, что это можно сделать как-то через zip архив (не очень понял как он создается). Подскажите пожалуйста, кто в курсе, как это правильно делается.

**UPD** Поменял урл на "jdbc:h2:file:./aleksei", который требует расположения файла aleksei.h2.db в корне приложения. Из Эклипса всё запускается, но когда я экспортирую проект в jar, там корнем становится папка src, и этот путь уже не актуален. Кто знает как это пофиксить?

Comment: исключение вылетает где?

Comment: @Etki, При первом запросе в базу

Comment: Надо внимательно читать stacktrace там должно быть подробно всё расписано. Надо внимательно читать [tutorial](http://www.h2database.com/html/tutorial.html#connecting_using_jdbc) про строку подключения к базе (url) локально и удалённо, про запуск базы в in-memory, локальном и серверном режиме.

Comment: @Igor Kudryashov, добавил полный exception в первый пост

Comment: Код добавьте где исключение возникает

Comment: @Artem Konovalov, добавил

Comment: у вас файл такой создан? а права на него какие выставлены?

Comment: я скопировал файл aleksei.h2.db из своей директории пользователя и засунул в корень с проектом. К файлу стоит полный доступ..

Comment: Путь вида /dir/dir2 является абсолютным, и следовательно поиск происходит от корневой директории (не текущей директории, и не директории пользователя!) Путь вида ./dir определяется от текущей директории в которой запущена программа.  Варианты решения, прописать абсолютный путь либо запускать программу из корректной директории

Comment: Если вы хотите хранить файл базы данных в папке проекта, попробуйте такой url 'jdbc:h2:aleksei'. Либо с помощью системного свойства 'user.dir'  получить текущий каталог и " склеить" его с именем файла.

Comment: @Igor Kudryashov, url типа 'jdbc:h2:aleksei' не работает (файл бд находится в корне проекта).

Comment: А что говорит `System.getProperty("user.dir")`?

Comment: @Igor Kudryashov, он показывает корень проекта: C:\Users\Алексей\workspace\FirstWords, где  FirstWords - название проекта.

Comment: Тогда напишу ответ на ваш вопрос...

Answer (score 0):

Используйте такой URL для подключения к базе

```
String url = "jdbc:h2:file:" + System.getProperty("user.dir") + System.getProperty("file.separator") + "aleksei";

BasicDataSource  bds = new BasicDataSource();
bds.setUrl(url);
```

где "aleksei" имя файла базы данных. Надеюсь вы понимаете, что у пользователя должны быть права на запись в этот файл.

Comment: Этот способ тоже работает только в IDE. Если экспортировать проект. то по прежнему nullpointer. Просто корень проекта до экспорта это  C:\Users\Алексей\workspace\FirstWords, а после экспорта корнем становится папка src.

Comment: "used.dir" указывает на каталог из которого "стартует" ваша программа.  Всё  будет зависеть от того как её запускаете. Скомпилированный jar не должен иметь никакой привязки к папкам на диске, если вы не  сделали это специально.